# HDMI sound: omxplayer works but not aplay

Tags: audio, hdmi, speech-synthesis

I want to use text-to-speech programs like festival and espeak, but they don't produce any sound.

I'm able to play sounds with omxplayer, but aplay, festival, and espeak are all muted.

I've tried tweaking /boot/config.txt and modprobe'ing, to no effect. Any tips?

pulseaudio is *not* installed.

Using official Raspbian (wheezy) on a Raspberry Pi model B+.

- Linux raspberrypi 3.12.28+ #709 PREEMPT Mon Sep 8 15:28:00 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux

Answer (score 5):

[Fixed it](https://gist.github.com/mcandre/b11c0817d0f3976a9840).

1. Connect Raspberry Pi to HDMI TV.
2. Boot Raspbian.
3. Edit `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`.
4. Change the line `pcm.front cards.pcm.front` to `pcm.front cards.pcm.default`.
5. Reload alsa: `sudo alsa reload`
6. Confirm audio is now working: `aplay /usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Animal/Kitten.wav`