# Raspbian, no audio HDMI, have tried all the troubleshooting I can find

Tags: raspbian, audio, hdmi, setup

I know this is a noob question, so I apologise in advance!

I've been googling for hours, have ran through all the steps for troubleshooting sound through HDMI; un-commenting the config file sound parts, updating sound drivers, forcing HDMI audio output. Nothing seems to work, I was hoping someone here might be able to give me a hint...

Can post any info needed, I am a noob so am not sure what would be required.

Appreciate any help anyone can give me! Am running the latest Raspbian package, on a raspberry pi 2, it is connected to a TV through HDMI. No sound through the jack either.

Comment: Have you tried `alsamixer`?

Comment: think i tried sudo apt-get install alsa-utils, sudo modprobe snd-bcm2835, amixer cset numid=3 2; It can play alsa tests and the speaker test but with no audio

Comment: @goldilocks If it helps - lsmod states
cfg80211  386508 0
rfkill   16651 1 cfg80211
snd_bcm2835  18649 0
snd_pcm   73475 1 snd_bcm2835
snd_seq   53078 0
snd_seq_device 5628 1 snd_seq
snd_timer  17704 2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd    51038 5 sbd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_seq_device
joylev   8879 0
evdev   9950 2
8192cu   528365 0
uio_pdrv_genirq 2958 0
uio    8119 1 uio_pdrv_genirq

Comment: I meant have you checked the output volume with the mixer.  I doubt that is the problem, but it sounds like you've done everything else.

Comment: @goldilocks Sorry! Yeah I have, it's at 50%

Comment: Did the sound ever work?  I don't know if the composite jack is completely separate from the HDMI but I'd guess it is, meaning it's probably *not* broken hardware.  But if there is some component common to them, then it could be that.  I guess there is something inside the SoC which would count as such.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest... regrettably I didn't check, I was focused on trying to get it working through HDMI, not sure if there's a way to check this? It doesn't work now, but presumably because I've routed everything through HDMI

Comment: @goldilocks It does work through a speaker - tempted to give up with HDMI

Comment: Have a look at these if you haven't yet: [Q&A 1](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32717/5538) -- [Q&A 2](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26170/5538).

Comment: @goldilocks have altered the config file already, will give the alsa.conf a shot. Thank you for all of your help anyway, much appreciated, know it's annoying troubleshooting basics.

Answer (score 4):

After going through all the answers I found what worked for me after more than an hour.As simple as right click on the speaker and change it to hdmi.

Comment: Upvote. It took me half an hour because this post is not on top.

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry Pi 4B has two HDMI mini-ports.  My problem was I was using the wrong mini-hdmi port. The HDMI port next to the power port will output audio, the other port does not.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem found the solution on a forum. Edit the config.txt file by doing `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

Either add or uncomment the line "hdmi_drive=2" then ctrl-o and Enter to write the changes and ctrl-x to exit the nano text editor. Reboot and the HDMI sound will work.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the config.txt file by doing sudo nano /boot/config.txt

Either add or uncomment the line "hdmi_drive=2" then ctrl-o to write the changes and ctrl-x to exit the nano text editor. Reboot and the HDMI sound will work.

that worked for me. Actually it had "hdmi_drive=2" remmed out as "#hdmi_drive=2" just had to take out the # and then reboot worked great.

Answer (score 1):

So the above answer about VLC player put me on track that it's definitely something about choosing a proper audio output. I managed to find a solution by running `alsamixer`. The command gave me my default device which was "Headphones", I clicked F6 to list all devices and both HDMI outputs were there. To change the default device you need to create/edit `/etc/asound.conf` and add these lines:

```
defaults.pcm.card <NUM>
defaults.ctl.card <NUM>
```

Replace the `<NUM>` with the number of your HDMI output you found on alsamixer, in my case it was 0: Headphones, 1: vc4-hdmi-0, 2: vc4-hdmi-1.

I hope that'll help.

Comment: Daniel Kusy
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/140730/daniel-kusy Your post:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133183/140766 Your solution saves my night here! Kudos to you! I just realized tonight I lost sound on HDMI on Bullseye (fresh installed; n it was working normally before on Buster). Thank you so much man! :)

Comment: This was spot on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, `alsa`:

Edit `config.txt` so that:

```
hdmi_drive=2 (this forces HDMI mode)
```

If this does not work, try:

```
hdmi_group=1
```

or:

```
hdmi_group=4
(these force CEA mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with audio through HDMI, try the following:

1. Open the "Terminal" in the upper right hand corner.
2. When it opens, type in: `sudo raspi-config`
3. With the down arrow on your keypad, scroll down to 7 Advanced Options and hit enter
4. With the down arrow on your keypad, scroll down to A9 Audio and hit enter
5. With the down arrow on you keypad, scroll down to 2 Force HDMI
6. Use the right arrow on your keypad to highlight  and hit enter
7. Use the right arrow on your keyboard to highlight  and hit enter
8. Reboot your Raspberry Pi and see if your audio now works

If that does not work, try changing your config.txt.  To do so:

1. Reboot your Raspberry Pi
2. As it is starting up, you will see a screen with a drawing of a Raspberry and the words "For recovery mode, hold Shift"
3. As soon as you see that screen, hold down the Shift key on your keyboard and keep holding it down until a screen comes up with the Noobs menu
4. At the top there will be a series of icons.  One will be a drawing of a pencil and paper labeled "Edit config (e)".  Click on that icon and the Config editor will open
5. Under the `config.txt` tab of the Config editor, scroll down to the section that says:
   "# uncomment to force a specific HDM mode rather than DVI.  This can make audio work in"
   "# DMT (computer monitor) modes"
   "# hdmi_drive=2"
6. Uncomment the HDMI option by deleting the # in front of it, so the section now reads:
   "# uncomment to force a specific HDM mode rather than DVI.  This can make audio work in `#DMT (computer monitor)` `modes hdmi_drive=2`
7. Click OK to close the Config editor
8. Click the icon at the top labeled Exit (Esc) Hopefully that will work and you will now have audio with your HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar problem when my HDMI cable was plugged in during boot. But when the cable was unplugged at boot time, it worked.

However you should be able to play sound through the OMX Player using the -o option. You can chose between hdmi, local, both, alsa[:device], where local refers to the jack output. So start from

```
omxplayer -o both file.mp3
```

to see if it is a software or hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every solution in here and i couldn't get the HDMI audio to work. I gave up and put all the options back to how they came by default but then I've found out that when I play an audio file using this command: `omxplayer -o both file.mp3`, the audio was working so I've decided to give it one more try and I've finally found the solution. None of the things in the config file will affect your audio so I think the best way is to put them back as they were by default and then open a console and do exactly this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-utils*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsamixer*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install alsamixer
sudo reboot
```

Then select the HDMI output using the speaker icon in the taskbar and that's it. I hope it works for you!

I've been able to find out this solution because of the omxplayer (that worked) which is a very basic music player that doesn't use the alsa driver, instead it has it's own drivers named openmax, so the problem had to be coming from the alsa drivers.

**If it's still not working after doing what I've said above**, then you could also try to uncomment `hdmi_drive=2` in `/boot/config.txt` to force HDMI mode. (To do this you have to open up a console, write `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` and the file will open, navigate down to `hdmi_drive` and delete the `#` that's before it, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, hit <kbd>Y</kbd> and enter then enter once again. After that `reboot` the system and pray :))

Answer (score 0):

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 b plus which I have plugged into a TV. I had the same issue with no audio through the HDMI. I worked my way through most of the suggestions here. In the end for me it worked once I set

```
hdmi_group=4 (these force CEA mode)
```

As per Marius' post (thank you)

```
hdmi_drive=2
```

as well. I haven't tested to see if both settings are needed or just one of them.

P.S. I also tried uninstalling Alsa (as per Frank's post) but couldn't get it to reinstall. I reinstalled Raspbian to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

The VLC player has an Audio tab.  Changing that to digital will work. The problem is that Chrome does not have that option so you cannot force it to digital.

I have not tried all of the above options but there is clearly an issue with an unmodified Raspbian installation.

Comment: Note that Raspbian sound system was [changed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118983/33476) last year, so answers to a question from 2015 may not apply to you if your system is up to date.